# How can I stop eclipse+git on windows from screwing with file permissions?

Tags: eclipse, git, permissions, egit

We have files that should be executable, and are happily executable in git, but then editing and committing the file from Eclipse on Windows results in the file mode being changed to remove executability.

This happens regardless of whether core.filemode is set to true or false.

Comment: I presume you are using Egit? Did you try to verify the behavior of other git implementations like msysgit, or `git config --global core.filemode false`?

Comment: You said that `core.filemode` setting seems immaterial.  Have you checked the value of `core.filemode` in project-root/.git/config.  Values in $HOME/.gitconfig will be overridden by those in project-root/.git/config.

Comment: msysgit looks to work fine, so that's what we'll be using instead. core.filemode was definitely set as false inside the project's .git/config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically egit seems to be too naive for our purposes (breaking file permissions is the problem, but it also doesn't seem to support git-svn) so we're using [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) instead - we have to manually refresh in Eclipse after switching branches etc, but that's a small enough sacrifice compared to it breaking our code.

Answer (score 1):

There are recent fixes for the filemode problems post 1.2, e.g. use the nightly build.